# Build a firebase / fanout.io like service on amazon web services aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda

I am using firebase to notify web browsers (javascript clients) about changes on specific topics. I am very happy with it. However I would really like to (only) use aws web services.

Unfortunately I am not able to determine whether it is possible to build such a service on aws. I am not talking about having EC2 instances running some firebase / fanout.io alternatives. I am talking about utilizing services such as lambda, dynamodb streams, SNS & SQS.

Are there any socket notification services available or is it possible to achieve something similar by using the provided services?

Comment: Note to those voting to close this question: it is **not** just a server or infrastructure **administration** question. the OP is asking how to construct a service with reference architecture programming tools provided by AWS. Lambda in particular is a service that requires the developer to write code in order to be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into this very recently with the same idea, but eventually I came down on just using fanout. AWS does not provide server-push HTTP notification services out of the box.

- Lambda functions are billed per 100 ms, so any long-polling against lambda will end up billing for the entirety of the time the client is connected.
- SNS does not provide long polling to browsers; the available clients are geared towards mobile, email, HTTP/S, and other Amazon products like Lambda and SQS.
- SQS would require a dedicated queue per client as it does not support broadcast.

Now, if the lambda pricing doesn't bother you, you could possibly do this:

1. Write a lambda function that is called via the API service that opens up a connection to SQS and waits for a message. The key is to start the lambda call from HTTP, but within the function wait on the queue (using Boto, for example, if you are writing this in Python). This code would need to create a queue dedicated to servicing one particular client, uniquely keyed by something like a GUID that is passed in by the client.
2. Link to the lambda function using the Amazon API service.
3. Call the lambda function via the API from the browser and wait for it to either receive a message on the dedicated SQS queue or timeout, probably using long-polling both in the API connection and the SQS connection. Fully draining the queue (or at least taking as many messages in a batch up to some limit) would be advisable here as well in order to reduce the number of calls to the API.
4. Publish your event to the dedicated SQS queue associated with the client. This will require the publisher to know the client's unique key.
5. Return the event read from SQS as the result of the lambda call.

Some problems with this approach:

1. Lambda pricing - not terribly expensive, but something like fanout is basically free
2. You would need a dedicated SQS queue per client; cleanup might become a problem
3. SQS bills on number of calls, which includes checking for a message. Long-polling SQS will alleviate some of this
4. You would need to write the JavaScript client to call the lambda API endpoint repeatedly in a long-polling fashion
5. Lambda is currently limited as to the number of concurrently running functions it supports (100 right now but you can contact support to bump that up)

Some benefits with this approach:

1. SQS queues are persistent, so unless a message is processed successfully it will go back on the queue after the visibility timeout
2. You can set up CloudWatch to monitor all of the API, Lambda, and SQS events

**Other Notes**

1. You could call the SQS APIs directly from the browser by using Lambda to issue temporary security credentials via STS. Receiving a message in JavaScript is documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html#Receiving_a_message  I do not, however, know off the top of my head if you would run into cross-domain issues.
2. Your only other option, if it *must* be all AWS, is to use load-balanced EC2 instances running something like fanout as you mentioned.

Using fanout is very little work: it's both extremely affordable and already built and tested.

Comment: Since the software behind fanout is open source, did you also consider self hosting it on aws?

Comment: @user3211074 I did not... I highly value managed infrastructure. I have a lot of experience with infrastructure operations, large and small, and managed infrastructure is almost always worth the price. Also, there do not appear to be any fanout.io preconfigured AMIs, adding to the operational burden. Do you have some other requirements that are leading you so heavily against a 3rd party vendor?

Comment: No, actually there are no requirements leading against 3rd party vendors. It's is just a wish to keep everything within aws. Many thanks for you advice.

Comment: Using SQS as the backend to provide long polling to your clients is useful, but instead of using Lambda you could use an ElasticBeanstalk app.  Alternatively your Lambda function could vend AWS keys to have clients directly consume SQS using STS to provide temporary credentials.

Comment: The main consideration with Electric Beanstalk is that you will always have reserve EC2 capacity running whether you need it or not. Lambda only charges for what you actually use. STS is an interesting idea.